# Ways to refresh a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, refresh

I have an Android app with a ListView. Every row is generated dinamically by SQLIte query results. When users click on a item, the app should refresh the list with the "content" of that item, generated by another SQLite query, and so on.
I tried to "refresh" the activity creating a new intent and sending it to the same activity. Activity name is ShopActivity

```
ListView list_content = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforshop));
list_content.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              

            // ID and text of selected item
            long selected_id = id;
            String selected_name = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element)).getText();

            // New intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            intent.setClassName(ShopActivity.this, ShopActivity.class.getName());

            // Passing data and refreshing activity
            intent.putExtra("id", selected_id);
            intent.putExtra("name", selected_name);
            intent.putExtra("type", "");
            startActivity(intent);
        }       
});
```

In this way LogCat shows me a lot of warnings about Bundle. It seems that app cannot start activity.

Is there another way to "refresh" ListView? Is this implementation correct?

Comment: When the data of your list needs to be updated, you should try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter and possibly invalidate() on your ListView in order to request that the view redraw itself

Answer (score 1):

```
// New intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setClassName(ShopActivity.this, ShopActivity.class.getName());
```

This does not make a new Intent, this reuses the existing one... Re-using an Intent like this will throw a lot of warning and exception when you resume this Activity. In order to create a new Intent you need to use the keyword `new`.

But you don't really need to reload your entire Activity, simply fetch a new Cursor and use `CursorAdapter#swapCursor()` to refresh your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to refresh your `ListView` you should think of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` of your adapter. this method tells your adapter that the provided data has changed and that it should update the list view.

So you should add the new data to your adapter and then call this method.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're viewing the details, don't use the same activity to view them. Add a new `ShopDetailActivity` and direct the user there on click, that way the user can press back to go to the original list (plus get the nice transition animation).

Comment: Yes, finally I decided to follow this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of handling lists and details is to use Fragments. The advantage of this is that on large-screen devices, both the list and the detail can be visible at the same time.

Using one Activity to show both list and detail is messy. At the very least, use two Activities.